# INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE in android

Tags: java, android

Now, I am trying to modify the original code about the contact part in android packages\apps\Contacts.
My compiler environment is eclpise + JDK1.7 + WIN7 (64)+AndroidSDK(2.3.3)
The program compiled is correct,but Simulator run error.

bellow Console:

```
[2012-09-16 15:14:46 - com.android.contacts.DialtactsActivity] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2012-09-16 15:14:46 - com.android.contacts.DialtactsActivity] Device API version is 10 (Android 2.3.6)
[2012-09-16 15:14:46 - com.android.contacts.DialtactsActivity] Uploading com.android.contacts.DialtactsActivity.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-09-16 15:14:48 - com.android.contacts.DialtactsActivity] Installing com.android.contacts.DialtactsActivity.apk...
[2012-09-16 15:14:56 - com.android.contacts.DialtactsActivity] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE
[2012-09-16 15:14:56 - com.android.contacts.DialtactsActivity] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2012-09-16 15:14:57 - com.android.contacts.DialtactsActivity] Launch canceled!
```

Bellow Logcat errors:
Package com.android.contacts has no signatures that match those in shared user android.uid.phone; ignoring!

From the net get solution,I get rid of code

```
 " android:sharedUserId="android.uid.shared"
    android:sharedUserLabel="@string/sharedUserLabel" " in AndroidManifest.xml.
```

that is ok.

but There was a new error.

```
"Could not find class 'com.android.phone.CallLogAsync', referenced from method com.android.contacts.TwelveKeyDialer.<init>"

"Could not find class 'com.android.phone.CallLogAsync$GetLastOutgoingCallArgs', referenced from method com.android.contacts.TwelveKeyDialer.queryLastOutgoingCall"
```

run is error.  I don't have a solution. can you give me some guidance Suggestions?

Comment: which api number avd are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [INSTALL\_FAILED\_SHARED\_USER\_INCOMPATIBLE while using shared user id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205159/install-failed-shared-user-incompatible-while-using-shared-user-id)