# Installing com.google.android.gms on emulator, packet exist error

Tags: android, android-emulator, xamarin.android, google-play-services

I'm trying to install com.google.android.gms v 3.0.27 on my android 4.2 emulator . But when I run adb install. it execute some minuets and the say:

```
INSTALLATION_FAILURE_PACKAGE_EXIST
```

the emulator by defualt has version 2... of this package but I want to update it. What should I do?

**EDIT**

I tried to uninstall. After executing command, CMD just show the help of adb unistall. 
I tried to install it on another emulator, Now I get this error:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE]
```

Comment: its saying: package already exist

Comment: And by the way if you are trying to implement map to emulator it wont work maybe just this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar/13734937#13734937

Comment: I now that it is exist but I want to update it. because in my app I use 3.0.27 and in the emulator had installed 2.0+ . Also @sercan for installing both apk file on the link I get above error

Answer (score 2):

This will reinstall it:

```
adb install -r com.google.android.gms.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to uninstall the the old version first. You can do this with ADB:

```
adb uninstall com.google.android.gms
```

Comment: Please see my edit, when I try to unistall it. CMD just show help of the command

Answer (score 0):

The emulator by default doesn't has those files, this is one of the reasons that `Google Map API V2` doesn't work on the emulator environment. So you can just create a new `AVD` and install you `.apk` file there or use the uninstall option as mentioned.

Comment: @HuseinBehbudiRad, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205159/install-failed-shared-user-incompatible-while-using-shared-user-id