# Android error: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE]

Tags: apk

I'm getting this error and don't know how to fix this:
When trying to run an Android app on a real device (NEXUS4(rooted) in my case) I'm getting the following error in the Console:

> pkg: /data/local/tmp/test.apk
>   Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE]

I've try to google this error and have got some solutions:

1. Delete the source with "android.uid.system".
   ->The error fixed but I need to use SharedUserID for system permission so I can't take this.
2. Use platform.pk8 and platform.x509.pem from "build\target\product\security" to signature my app.
   ->Same error occured.
3. Add my own UID(the xml below(copied from system)) into packages.xml and reset.
   ->The app disappeard from my phone after reset. I've no idea why I can't see it.

   ```
   <shared-user name="android.uid.cc" userId="10910">
       <sigs count="1">
           <cert index="2" />
       </sigs>
       <perms>
            ...
       </perms>
   </shared-user>
   ```

None of these solutions solved the problem.
My andriod version is 4.4.2.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Please, consider giving more details about your problem so we can try to help you, or just mark the question to be closed. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In other answer [INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE while using shared user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205159/install-failed-shared-user-incompatible-while-using-shared-user-id) they describe to do:

I got the solution for now .I followed the steps as follows

```
1) Removed existing application (if it is already installed )
2) Removed share user ID from android manifest
3) Bulid the application.
4) Now enter share user ID again
5) build the application 1 more time
```

and It works !!!

Thanks to Hemant

Answer (score 0):

I met this error too, when run application show a dialog, most message is saying

> INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_COMPATIBLE

Except this error above you mentioned, and another error in my logcat is:

```
Error using StatusBarManagerService - java.lang.SecurityException on android.permission.STATUS_BAR
```

Lastly, add platform debug key fixed it.