# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE] while Installing apk

Tags: android

I tried to Install one apk by using adb in my machine which is Ubuntu 12.04(64-bit)

But i got following below error 
**Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE]**

I tried the method which is given in [INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE while using shared user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205159/install-failed-shared-user-incompatible-while-using-shared-user-id) but still i cannot resolve the error

So can anyone please let me know how to resolve this error

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205159/install-failed-shared-user-incompatible-while-using-shared-user-id