# Error on installing signed apk (using libgdx) on device

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I know that my device is clean, the debug version of the apk was uninstall but still i got an error `INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE` while installing the release version. See below error message obtained:-

```
Information:Gradle tasks [installRelease]
```

> :android:preBuild UP-TO-DATE :android:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :android:checkReleaseManifest :android:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE :core:processResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :core:classes UP-TO-DATE :core:jar UP-TO-DATE
>   :android:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :android:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2310Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :android:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :android:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42310Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :android:prepareReleaseDependencies :android:compileReleaseAidl
>   UP-TO-DATE :android:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :android:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :android:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE :android:mergeReleaseAssets
>   UP-TO-DATE :android:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :android:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :android:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :android:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :android:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :android:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :android:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :android:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
>   :android:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE :android:compileReleaseSources
>   UP-TO-DATE :android:preDexRelease UP-TO-DATE :android:dexRelease
>   UP-TO-DATE :android:validateReleaseSigning :android:packageRelease
>   UP-TO-DATE :android:zipalignRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   :android:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE :android:installRelease Installing
>   APK 'android-release.apk' on 'Nexus 4 - 5.1.1' Unable to install
>   C:\Users\Kevin\testgdx\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release.apk
>   com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to finalize session :
>   INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.testgdx.game.android
>   signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!
>     at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackages(Device.java:915)   at
>   com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackages(ConnectedDevice.java:113)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice$installPackages$0.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.InstallVariantTask.install(InstallVariantTask.groovy:119)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:226)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:208)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:589)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:572)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:310)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:54)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:49)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)    at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 06:03:56
>   E/C:\Users\Kevin\testgdx\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release.apk:
>   Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE:
>   Package com.testgdx.game.android signatures do not match the
>   previously installed version; ignoring! :android:installRelease FAILED
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':android:installRelease'.
>   com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to finalize session :
>   INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.testgdx.game.android
>   signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!
>   Information:BUILD FAILED Information:Total time: 6.214 secs
>   Information:1 error Information:0 warnings Information:See complete
>   output in console

Comment: did you use a different keystore?

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205159/install-failed-shared-user-incompatible-while-using-shared-user-id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to uninstall the debug app first. You are trying to install an app with the same package, but a different signature.

This is a security mechanism that tries to prevent someone making changes to your app. The changed app has to be signed with your key and if it's a different key (which is the case of the automatically signed debug version of your app), Android will refuse it.

Comment: Thank you, i have to use the same key for debug mode and release mode

Answer (score 1):

try using uninstallAll gradle task to uninstall the app and then try installRelease again
It worked for me :)