# INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE App not installed on Lollipop device

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-keystore

I am installing the released version of my Xamarin.Android app on the Lollipop device. For this, I have performed the following steps:

1. Changed the mode to Release mode.
2. Provided the required permissions and changes in the Android manifest, used android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
3. I generated the keystore file for Android 5.1(Lollipop) with the platform keys platform.pk8 and platform.x509.pem files(downloaded from the Android Google Git repository) using :

   ./keytool-importkeypair -k /Android5.keystore -p android -pk8 platform.pk8 -cert platform.x509.pem -alias platform

This generated the .keystore file.

4. After this, I provided this keystore file for signing my application project and build the project.

Now when I am installing the apk signed on an Android 5.1 emulator, the application is installed and is running perfectly. But when I am trying to install the same apk on the Android 5.1 mobile device, it showing app not installed.

And the error which I pulled from logs is INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE error.

Comment: Based on your error, it caused by shared user ID, user ID is existed, uninstall the other apps that use the same shared ID and install APK's that were built and signed the same was as the other(s). Here is a similar thread, you can refer to it https://stackoverflow.com/a/15637929/10627299